# What is the order of execution of sql functions in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to do transformation on the string elements found by REGEXP_REPLACE but function SUBSTR look like executed before REGEXP_REPLACE.

I was unable to found any limitations of what `replacement` should be

```
WITH tabA AS
  (SELECT "[\"5cc623dd-41f5-42d9-9637-a169af42e2b1\",\"6cc623dd-41f5-42d9-9637-a169af42e2b1\"]" as myids
  union all
  SELECT "[\"5cc623dd-41f5-42d9-9637-a169af42e2b1\"]" as myids
  )

SELECT
  myids,
  REGEXP_REPLACE(myids,"\"(.{36})\"",SUBSTR("\\1",0,8)) as ccc,
  SUBSTR(myids,0,8) as ddd
FROM tabA;
```

I expect only first 8 characters of each regex to be output, but instead getting all 36.

Expected to see:

```
5cc623dd,6cc623dd
5cc623dd
```

Comment: you might want to provide example of expected output (based on shown input)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your query, SUBSTR(...) is part of input to function REGEXP_REPLACE, so it must be evaluated prior to calling REGEXP_REPLACE().

You must do the SUBSTR equivalent as part of your regular expression, like in below example

```
WITH tabA AS
  (SELECT "[\"5cc623dd-41f5-42d9-9637-a169af42e2b1\",\"6cc623dd-41f5-42d9-9637-a169af42e2b1\"]" as myids
  union all
  SELECT "[\"5cc623dd-41f5-42d9-9637-a169af42e2b1\"]" as myids
  )

SELECT
  myids,
  REGEXP_REPLACE(myids,"\"(.{8}).{28}\"","\\1") as ccc
FROM tabA;
```

Output:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
|                                      myids                                      |         ccc         |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
| ["5cc623dd-41f5-42d9-9637-a169af42e2b1","6cc623dd-41f5-42d9-9637-a169af42e2b1"] | [5cc623dd,6cc623dd] |
| ["5cc623dd-41f5-42d9-9637-a169af42e2b1"]                                        | [5cc623dd]          |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: That's answer my question of 'order of execution', while @MikhailBerlyant answer below provide options to do more complex things - e.g. apply functions like SHA256().

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH tabA AS (
  SELECT "[\"5cc623dd-41f5-42d9-9637-a169af42e2b1\",\"6cc623dd-41f5-42d9-9637-a169af42e2b1\"]" AS myids UNION ALL
  SELECT "[\"5cc623dd-41f5-42d9-9637-a169af42e2b1\"]" AS myids
)
SELECT myids, 
  ( SELECT STRING_AGG(id)
    FROM UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(myids, r'"(.{8})-')) id
  ) ids  
FROM tabA
```

with result

```
Row myids                                                                           ids  
1   ["5cc623dd-41f5-42d9-9637-a169af42e2b1","6cc623dd-41f5-42d9-9637-a169af42e2b1"] 5cc623dd,6cc623dd    
2   ["5cc623dd-41f5-42d9-9637-a169af42e2b1"]                                        5cc623dd
```